# Rails 3 nesting resources or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a "Company" which has "Projects" within them. As time goes on we now need to add "Links" that are related to "Projects". My routes currently look like the following:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :projects do
    resources :links
  end
end
```

This seems wrong due to the nesting 2 levels deep. I also no longer have `new_company_project_path(@company)` anymore if I nest like this which now denies me to ever creating projects for a company.

I will need to add other models to relate to Projects in the coming months.

Here is my Projects model and my Links model as well..

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :link_name, :url, :description

  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, :presence => true

  validates :description, :presence => true,
                          :length   => { :minimum => 10 } 
end
```

It would seem nesting is not the proper way. If nesting is not the proper way, how does one go about saving the association? For example, in my current controller I save my nested objects by doing this:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :find_company

  def new
    @project = @company.projects.build
  end

  def create
    @project = @company.projects.build(params[:project])
    if @project.save
      flash[:notice] = "Project has been created."
      redirect_to [@company, @project]
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Project has not been created."
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  private
    def find_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end
end
```

I can't find too much info on this subject and the books I read before used nesting routes only 1 level deep and others don't nest at all.

So, what is the best way to do this so that I can have "Links" and other models related to "Projects" while "Projects" remain related to "Companies"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle it with shallow nested routes like this:

```
resources :companies do
  resources :projects
end

resources :projects do
  resources :links
  resources :sausages
  resources :patties
end
```

Then you have routes like new_company_project_path, new_project_link_path, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nested routes and "nesting" models are two different things.

Nesting your models the way you are doing it now seems to be OK.

As for the routes, consider making them `shallow`, as explained [here](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/9/7/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-shallow-routes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601780/rails-3-shallow-routes)